# C - copy array without duplicates

Tags: arrays, for-loop, nested, copy

for learning purposes I'm trying to copy an array to a new empty array -skipping the duplicates, my logic is that a nested for loop  will check for duplicates and when it finds one it will skip it's parent's counter.

however the resulting array is always the original array's last number, repeated N times.

EDIT: The program should work with unsorted arrays and when the duplicates aren't consecutive.

please help

full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
int array[10]={1,2,3,3,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int arrayB[10];
int i=0;
int j=0;
int lengthB=10;

// routine for copying array without duplicates
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++){

             if (array[i]==arrayB[j]) {
             lengthB--;
             i++;                  
        }
             else{
             arrayB[j]=array[i];
             }
        }

}        
//display copied array:
printf("\n");
for(i=0;i<lengthB;i++)
printf("%d\t",arrayB[i]);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however the resulting array is always the original array's last number, repeated N times.

This is because of this part of the code :

```
for(j=0;j<=i;j++){

         if (array[i]==arrayB[j]) {
         lengthB--;
         i++;                  
    }
         else{
         arrayB[j]=array[i];
         }
    }
}
```

When i reaches 10, you will be filling up arrayB from index 0 to 9 by the number 10, if you look closely at the 'else' clause.

Considering that you do not need to loop from j=0 every time you look at the number from the original array, and you can identify replicates within the original array itself, try this instead (replaces everything in between your two comments):

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
  while(array[i+1] == array[i]){
    i++;
    lengthB--;
  }
  arrayB[j] = array[i];
  j++;
}
```

Answer to your Edit :

try this :

```
for (i=0;i<10;i++) {
  isDuplicate = 0;
  for(k = 0; k<j; k++){
    if(arrayB[k] == array[i]){
      lengthB--;
      isDuplicate=1;
      break;
    } 
  }
  if(isDuplicate) continue;

  arrayB[j] = array[i];
  j++;
}
```

If the duplicates can occur anywhere, you have to check for the duplicate from the beginning of the new array whenever you copy a new number from the original array.

A new iterator (k) was introduced, as well as a flag variable (isDuplicate). This may not be the best solution, but works nonetheless.

Comment: how could i make this work if the array wasn't sorted or if the duplicates weren't consecutive?

Comment: It would be okay if the array wasn't sorted, but the duplicates would have to be consecutive. If you want the duplicates to be filtered even when they are not consecutive, the code would look rather different. Would you want me to make that edit?